# Brackets Git error when I clone button click

Tags: git, brackets

After installing 'Brackets Git' if I click 'Clone' button, error message pops up.

I tried to reinstall it but it didn't work.

**error message pic**

```
 Expected Error:
 root is not empty, be sure you have deleted hidden files.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clone in an empty repository, in order to a git clone operation (even through Brackets Git) to proceed.

Make sure you select an empty folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I should paste git URL first than make a new folder.

Comment: Yes, it will create the folder.